# The PayPal Void Endpoint in the sandbox environment is returning no response to a valid request, any solution?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox, endpoint

I am working with the paypal sandbox v1 api and I am unable to get the following endpoint to return any response with a valid payment_id and oauth_token:

Endpoint: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}/void`

Headers:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

The access token is generated with the same V1 sandbox api and is valid, and when I request the general payment information endpoint: `/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}` I get a valid response with the correct payment details and `state = "created"` which is inline with the documentation and requirements of a situation where you can void a payment.

Yet with all the above completed, the endpoint seems to do quite literally nothing!

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I am working in python.)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The v1/payments API is deprecated, why are you working with it in sandbox? Use v2/checkout/orders ; see the [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), its backend samples are in node.js but that can of course be implemented in any language/environment including python.

Payments/orders that have not been authorized cannot be voided. Simply forget about them and do not authorize nor capture them.

Comment: Is there a vast difference between the 2 api versions? And if so, is it actually dangerous/vulnerable to use V1?

Comment: it is old, deprecated, and there is no reason to use it for new integrations, so those questions aren't even worth investigating or having an answer to